# Observables that encode all the information in a wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, mathematical-physics, observables

Let's consider the position space representation of the single particle Hilbert space and for simplicity let's stick to one dimension: $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Let's say a collection of observables $O_1,...,O_n$ *resolves* the Hilbert space if knowledge of the probability distributions $\mathbb{P}_{O_j}$ corresponding to each observable specifies the wavefunction $\psi$ uniquely (up to global phase). I.e. if $O_1 = X$ and $O_2 = P$, then we'd say $X,P$ resolved the space if we could reconstruct $\psi$ from knowledge of the position-space probability distribution, which has density $|\psi|^2(x)$ and the momentum-space probability distribution, which has density $|\hat \psi|^2(p)$.

It seems like $X,P$ should resolve the space (that complete knowledge of the position and momentum distributions of $\psi$ should uniquely determine $\psi$). But this turns out to  be false, e.g. see [here](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0334270000001569) a paper by Corbett and Hurst. This says that a wavefunction $\psi$ holds more information than it's global phase (which is unphysical) and it's position and momentum distributions (which seems to be the only physical things). So there's is information missing when just knowing about position and momentum, and I'm trying to understand what the information is. Note here that we are in 1D, so there is no angular momentum.

The question is twofold then:

1. Is there a known "physical" (i.e. able to be interpreted as a physical quantity) observable $O$ that is not determined by $|\psi|^2(x), |\hat \psi|^2(p)$ for the particle in 1D.
2. Is there a (finite) collection of (hopefully physical) observables which "resolve" the space in the above specified sense. In this case, this collection of observables would specify entirely the physics of the state.

Edit: Not sure why I didn't realize this earlier, but it seems to me that the Hamiltonian is of course the natural physical observable we should consider. Suppose for definiteness we are the harmonic oscillator case:
$$H = \frac{P^2}{m} + k X^2.$$
Then I'm fairly sure the $H$ can't be determined by $|\psi|^2(x)$ and $|\hat \psi|^2(p)$. So the questions then specialize in this case to

1. Can we construct examples with the same position and momentum distributions but distinct energy distributions?
2. Are there conditions on the form of the Hamiltonian which ensure that the state of the particle is uniquely determined by knowledge of the position, momentum, and energy distributions?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly A bit of an imprecise property, admittedly. I think it seems like it'd be good enough to say that some element of the algebra generated by $X,P$ would be physical if the analogous quantity can actually be (approximately) measured for an actual 3D particle.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly See edit for a specific physical we probably ought to consider, which somewhat reduces the question to math again.

Comment: The set of observables that resolve the space is the same as the set of tomographically complete set of observables which, in turn, is the same as a set that spans the real vector space of Hermitian operators defined on the given Hilbert space. Since the Hilbert space of a particle on a line is infinite dimensional, the real vector space of all Hermitian operators defined on this Hilbert space is also infinite dimensional. So, you need infinitely many probability distributions to completely determine the wavefunction here.

Comment: For a simpler system such as a spin-1/2 particle, a set of observables that resolve the Hilbert space is simply the three Pauli operators taken together with the identity matrix. However, this is exceptionally simple. As you go to higher spins, such sets necessarily involve such operators that cannot be as simply physically interpreted as the Pauli matrices.

Comment: @DvijD.C. do you have a reference saying that a tomographically complete set of observables is the same as a spanning set for the real vector space of Hermitian operators? I think it isn't quite right actually, since one can verify that one can completely recover the state up to phase of a spin 1/2 system by knowing exactly two orthogonal spin measurements, e.g. knowledge of the $x$-spin distribution and $z$-spin distribution determines the $y$-spin distribution. But two Pauli matrices don't span the space of Hermitian operators.

Comment: The name "tomographically complete set of observables" is a very useful reference though, thanks!

Comment: Also I think maybe there might be something going on with what I said above depending on if we assume a priori that our state is pure, in which case what I said about spin 1/2 system I think is true, but it likely doesn't hold in the mixed case.

Comment: @PhysicalMathematics It can be proven easily, e.g., see the accepted answer to this question of mine: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/557336/20427. Your claim about spin-1/2 systems is not correct even for pure states. Each Pauli matrix is linearly independent of the other two Pauli matrices (and the identity) and this forbids one from doing what you claim to be able to do ;)

Comment: @DvijD.C. The accepted answer isn't quite precise; it seems to give a sufficient condition but not a necessary one. I don't really understand his argument about positivity not providing a relevant condition. Also I'm not sure how to convince you that you really only need 2 measurements for spin 1/2 short of writing out the computation, but counting degrees of freedom gives a good heuristic. For a $n$-dim space, there are $2n-2$ degrees of freedom in specifying a state ($2n$ real numbers minus phase and normalization). 1/2

Comment: Each measure of spin in a direction gives 1 real number of info (expectation value). So doing 2 measurements on a 2-dim system should nail down uniquely the 2 degree of freedom. This is born out by just writing everything out. 2/2

Comment: So you want two distinct & different  pure-state [Wigner functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_quasiprobability_distribution) with identical marginals. C&H claim they exist, but don't provide easy examples...

Comment: @PhysicalMathematics Yes, counting would suggest what you claim is true but it's not rigorous enough. What happens is that the two numbers you need to specify the state in a given basis are $p>0$ and $\theta\in[0, 2\pi)$ where $\sqrt{p}$ is the coefficient of $\vert \uparrow\rangle$ and $\sqrt{1-p}\exp{i\theta}$ is the coefficient of $\vert\downarrow\rangle$ -- but with only two distributions you only determine $p$ and $\sin\theta$ (or $\cos\theta$) and that's not sufficient to pin down $\exp{ i \theta}$. You need the third distribution to get the missing $\cos\theta$ (or $\sin\theta$).

Comment: [Better](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0034-4877(06)80008-X).

Comment: @DvijD.C. Yep you're right my bad. Thanks for pointing that out.